# "Whatever it costs, it doesn't matter" - Conditionals with "whatever"

Tags: conditionals, learning

What is the usage of *whatever*? Can I both use 'noun' and 'SVO' after 'whatever'?

> 1. Whatever the motivation , haphazard clinical practice led to death.
> 2. Whatever it costs, it doesn't matter.

Thank you

Comment: Are they both correct?

Comment: _Whatever the motivation_ is short for _Whatever the motivation **is**_; _whatever_ is an indefinite pronoun that introduces headless relative clauses (also known as embedded question complements) and it has to be followed by a clause, or at least the remains of a deceased clause.

Comment: Yes, they are fine, but I disagree somewhat with JL's analysis. See my answer

Comment: @John Lawler "Deceased clause"?

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are called **exhaustive conditional interrogatives** in which “whatever” is an interrogative determinative.

***Whatever the motivation,*** haphazard clinical practice led to death. This is a verbless clause functioning as an adjunct. It comprises an interrogative phrase followed by the subject, with the verb "be" understood: "whatever the motivation was".

We understand that haphazard clinical practices led to death no matter what x was, where x is some unknown motivation.

An 'exhaustive conditional' construction like this uses an interrogative clause to express a set of conditions that exhaustively cover the possibilities. It’s used because the interrogative expresses a question whose answers define an exhaustive set of conditions. The question here is "What was the motivation?" which has an open set of answers.

***Whatever it costs,*** it doesn't matter. The same applies here, except that that the interrogative adjunct clause is not reduced. We understand that for every possible x, where x is the cost, it doesn’t matter", so all possibilities are exhausted. The question here is "what does it cost?" which has an open set of answers.

Comment: +1 As you might have read recently, ;-), Pullum has used the fact that conditional protases with *if* can be verbless clauses to argue that they are *not* interrogative clauses. Many grammars treat this kind of conditional protasis as a type of relative clause construction  (see JL's comment above). Do you feel either that a) *if* antecedents might be interrogative clauses or that b) this type of protasis may be a type of fused-relative construction?

Comment: Another interpretation from CaGEL presented as incontrovertible. At least J Lawler limits his interpretations to comments.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That doesn't seem very reasonable. This is a standard analysis. You'll notice that Bill and JL's answers are not in fact incompatible, There are indeed people who do not believe that phrases exist. That doesn't mean that people cannot refer to noun phrases in their answers. My comments to Bill were just part of an in-joke.

Comment: @Araucaria 'I disagree somewhat with JL's analysis. See my answer.' But the answer doesn't include 'According to the CaGEL analysis.' Actually, I prefer the analysis CaGEL gives here also, but, as Bill mentions in a comment, it's not the only one around. And JL is an acknowledged authority.  Answers presented as fiats when there are alternative analyses are misleading.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I should have been more specific. Bill's analysis is not incompatible with JL's, but John's is incompatible with Bill's. Notice that JL's comment seems to equate free relatives with 'embedded question complements', the latter being subordinate interrogative clauses, of course.

Comment: @Araucaria I do think the interrogative interpretation of the OP’s examples is the right one, though some see things differently. The bottom line is that ungoverned open exhaustive conditionals look a lot like fused relatives but don't function like them syntactically or contribute like them semantically. One obvious contrast is that the _wh_- elements in fused relatives are NPs, whereas in interrogatives they are clauses, cf. _They will do whatever we recommend_ (NP, fused relative) vs _They will still do that, whatever we recommend_. (clause, interrogative)

Comment: @Araucaria Looking at it now!

Comment: @BillJ Any thoughts?

Comment: @Araucaria Sorry, trying to get into it, but keep getting sidetracked. When do you have to submit the work?

Comment: @BillJ It's overdue :) But it doesn't matter. I'm still finishing another bit right now. If you do have any insights they'd be really appreciated, because I  understand and appreciate your analysis in general. But, if you're busy with other stuff, no worries :)