# dislocation with 'whoever' or 'whatever'

Tags: grammar, pronouns, relative-pronouns

CaGEL* has this section on 'dislocation' (Page 1411):

[image]

Can the dislocated NP be in the form of a fused relative construction headed by 'whoever' or 'whatever'?

Specifically, in the following set of examples, are [ii] and [iii] dislocated versions of the non-dislocated [i]?

> [1'] i ***Whoever her parents are** must be worried sick.*  [non-dislocated version?]
>
> ii ***Whoever her parents are**, **they** must be worried sick.* [left dislocation?]
>
> iii ***They** must be worried sick, **whoever her parents are**.* [right dislocation?]

Or, is ***whoever her parents are*** in [ii] and [iii] merely an exhaustive conditional adjunct meaning "no matter who her parents are"?

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddleston & Pullum

Comment: Does it matter what you call these constructions?  I think you should call them whatever you prefer.

Comment: @GregLee It's not just a matter of terminology, it's a matter of syntax. If it's dislocation, [ii] and [iii] are merely dislocated versions of [i]. But if it's not dislocation, they are syntactically different animals.

Comment: I would have phrased it, "Whoever they are, her parents must be worried sick." Or, "Her parents must be worried sick, whoever they are." That way you would have the pronouns together within the clauses in question, so there would be a lot less *ambiguity*. It should then be apparent that they're indeed dislocated clauses.

Comment: @Bread What do you mean, you'd have the pronouns together within clauses in question? Do you mean the pronoun _they_ is within the main clause in your version?

Comment: @Bread Also, I doubt your own version is clearly dislocation. I'd rather consider your version to have an exhaustive conditional adjunct.

Comment: When I googled *exhaustive conditional adjunct*, I got the following, which indicates that type of clause is verbless: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328109/whatever-it-costs-it-doesnt-matter-conditionals-with-whatever My dislocated clause has a constituent, and as in the examples given contain verbs.

Comment: *Do you mean the pronoun they is within the main clause in your version?* Of course not. You have *they* within the main clause in *your* version.

Comment: @Bread Many adjunct clauses can be "reduced" and verbless, which has nothing to do with whether the adjunct clause is exhaustive conditional type or some other type. For example, _When in doubt, ask Jack._ has a reduced adjunct clause _When in doubt_, but this adjunct is not an exhaustive conditional.

Comment: @Bread Then, what do you mean by "you'd have the pronouns together within clauses in question"?

Comment: The answer must be no because "[1] Whoever her parents are must be worried sick." is basically agrammatical in English, whereas the second and third of your new utterances are completely grammatical.

Comment: @Lambie When 'whoever' acts as a fuse relative word 'whoever her parents are' is an NP, which I think can in turn act as a subject.  So why do you say it's ungrammatical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructions in your [1'] ii and iii are **ambiguous** between being (a) **dislocations** and (b) **exhautive conditionals**. This corresponds to an ambiguity about whether *whoever her parents are* is (a) an **NP** (a fused relative) or (b) an **interrogative clause**.

Both ii and iii can be disambiguated by e.g. coordination with an appropriate construction, here shown on the example of ii:

Forcing the **left-dislocation** reading:

[2] ***Her husband*** and **whoever her parents are**, they must be worried sick.

Forcing the **exhautive conditional** reading:

[3] ***Whoever her parents are*** and **regardless of where they are**, they must be
       *worried sick.*

As we will see below, [2] involves a coordination of NPs: *her husband* is an NP and it couldn't be coordinated with an interrogative clause. Thus, [2] is a left dislocation.

Contrarily, in [3], *regardless of where they are* is an interrogative clause and it couldn't be coordinated with an NP. Thus, [3] involves a coordination of interrogative clauses; thus, it is an exhaustive conditional.

The key question is always whether *whoever her parents are* is an NP or an interrogative clause.

**Discussion**

What is used in [2] and [3] is the fact that ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), or CaGEL, as you call it, p. 1326)

> In the great majority of cases, coordinates belong to the same syntactic category, but a difference of category is generally tolerated where there is likeness of function.

The cases where the requisite likeness of function obtains are discussed in CGEL Ch. 15, §3.2 (*Coordination of unlike categories*, pp. 1326-1329). Suffices to say that none of those apply to [2] and [3]; this will become obvious below, because certain attempts at coordination will produce unacceptable sentences.

As we've been saying, the key question is whether *whoever her parents are* is an NP (if it is, it's a fused relative), or whether is is rather an interrogative clause. However, note that the same group of words may function sometimes as one, and sometimes as the other, depending on the context (CGEL, p. 987):

> [57]  i  *They will appoint Jones, **whoever we recommend**.*    [open interrogative] 
>            ii  *They will appoint **whoever we recommend**.*                         [fused relative]
>
> The underlined [boldfaced] sequence is in [i] an interrogative clause in adjunct function and in [ii] a fused relative construction functioning as object of *appoint*.<sup>16</sup> The free choice -*ever* compounds do not occur elsewhere in interrogative clauses—the *ever* in examples like 
>   *What ever could have come over her?* has a different sense, and is usually written as a separate word (see Ch. 10, §7.13).
>
> <sup><sup>16</sup>*Whomever* is possible as a formal alternant of whoever, especially in [57ii].</sup>

So, one key observation is that exhaustive conditionals employ **clauses**. CGEL gives two main syntactical ways to tell if the construction like *whoever we recommend* is a clause or an NP.

**Preposition fronting**

The first way is to see whether stranded prepositions can be fronted (note the mention of exhautive conditionals—which I have boldfaced—in the explanation that follows the example):

> [59]    i  *He always antagonised **whoever he worked with**.* 
>             ii  **He always antagonised **with whomever he worked**.*  
>            iii  *Now, **in whatever way government may be theoretically conceived**, 
>
>                  it is in practice a matter of the adjustment of a multiplicity of private interests.*
>
> In [i] we have a fused relative with a stranded preposition; as shown in [ii] the preposition cannot be placed in front of *whoever*. In ordinary interrogatives, both orders are possible: *I can't recollect who he worked with/with whom he worked*. But [ii] is ungrammatical because the preposition has been placed at the beginning of an NP rather than a clause. The difference between [i] and [ii] is thus comparable to that seen between *He always antagonised those who he worked with* and **He always antagonised with those whom he worked*. The ungoverned **exhaustive conditional**, however, is a clause and thus allows a  preposition to be placed in front position along with its complement, as illustrated in the attested example [iii]. This may be compared with the governed counterpart *no matter in what way government may be theoretically conceived*.

So, let's modify your example slightly by introducing a preposition;

[4]  i  a.  ***Whoever she originates from*** must be worried sick. 
          b.  ****From whomever she originates*** must be worried sick.
      ii  a.  ***Whoever she originates from***, they must be worried sick.
          b.  ***From whomever she originates,*** they must be worried sick.
     iii  a.  *Her husband and **whomever she originates from,** they must be worried sick.*
          b.  **Her husband and **from whomever she originates,** they must be worried sick.*

The fronted version i b. is not acceptable, which is good evidence that what we have there is an NP. However, ii b is acceptable as it stands. There is, however, a way to force an NP reading and make it unacceptable: we just attempt a coordination with another NP. This is done in iii: as expected, the stranded version (a.) is fine; here the *whomever she originates from* is forced to be read as an NP. The fronted version in (b.), however, can only be a clause, and so an attempt at coordination with an NP makes the sentence unacceptable.

**Place in the system of exhaustive conditionals**

The second syntax-based way that CGEL suggests for distinguishing between an interrogative clause an fused-relative NP concerns certain regularities that hold for exhaustive conditionals (pp. 988-989):

> Exhaustive conditionals are classified, as we have noted, on two cross-cutting dimensions, governed vs ungoverned and closed vs open:
>
> [60]                                       GOVERNED                                            UNGOVERNED 
>              closed     a. *They will appoint Jones [regardless*        b. *They will appoint Jones* 
>                                   ***of whether he's the best can-***                  ***whether he's the best***  
>                                   ***didate or not***].                                                 ***candidate or not***.
>              open       c. *They will appoint Jones [regardless*         d. *They will appoint Jones*
>  
>                                  ***of who we recommend***].                             ***whoever we recommend***.
>
> On one dimension, the relation of [a] to [b] is the same as that of [c] to [d]; and on another the relation of [a] to [c] is the same as that of [b] to [d]. These relationships are most simply described if in other respects the constructions are all alike—i.e. all involve interrogative clauses.

Let's do your [1'] i first,

[1']  i  ***Whoever her parents are*** must be worried sick.

If this were an example of an exhaustive conditional, it would be of an ungoverned closed type. It would thus have to have two counterparts: a closed-governed, and an open-ungoverned. But already with the governed counterpart we run into trouble:

[1']  i'  ****Regardless of who her parents are*** must be worried sick.

The story is different with your

[1']  ii  ***Whoever her parents are***, they must be worried sick.

Here it seems we can have a governerned version:

[1']  ii'  ***Regardless of who her parents are***, they must be worried sick.

But again, if we coordinate with an NP, we force an NP reading of *whoever her parents are*, and it becomes impossible to construct a governed counterpart:

[5]  i  *Her husband and **whoever her parents are**, they must be worried sick.*
      ii  **Her husband and **regardless of who her parents are**, they must be worried sick.*

**Conclusion**

Your sentence

[1']  ii  ***Whoever her parents are***, they must be worried sick.

is ambiguous between being a left dislocation (where *whoever her parents are* is an NP) and being an exhaustive conditional (where *whoever her parents are* is an interrogative clause). The ambiguity may be lifted by approriate coordination as in [2] and [3], as explained above. Only the case [1'] ii is treated explicitly; the right-dislocation case iii is treated the same way, with the same conclusions.

**References**

R. Huddleston and G. K. Pullum, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, UK, 2002).

Comment: Thank you for your excellent and rigorous answer. I too thought about coordination with another exhaustive conditional construction as in [3], but somehow I didn't think about that with another NP as in [2].

Comment: @JK2 No problem—thank you for posing an interesting question!

Comment: *CaGEL* or *CamGEL* is used by those writers mindful that *CamGEL* was written, at least in part, as a successor to the *Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (Quirk et al 1985) - which had already long been referred to as *CGEL*. Seeing as the two books may at least ins ome respects be seen as competitors, and because as H&P acknowledge, *CamGEL* wouldn't have existed were it not for *CGEL*, it was a bit remiss of them to choose a title with the same abbreviation!!! So, call it *CGEL* if you wish, but don't be surpised if people end up telling you *That's not what Quirk et al said!*

Comment: +1 from me. However, there's a bit of stuff you need to clear up there. The main thing for me, really, is that the protases in the governed constrcution are not interrogative clauses. *Regardless of ...* for example is a preposition phrase (which happens to tave an interrogative clause complement).

Comment: "regardless of where they are is an interrogative clause " (penultimate paragraph in introductory section) <--- It's a preposition phrase containing an interrogative, namely "where they are". ;-)